# MySQL query to get user where email equals some variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

First of all i don't know where to start doing this. That's why i am posting this question. Maybe you guys go for down-vote or close or flag it.

Here is the problem.

```
<?php
    $gmail = "dipesh@some.com"
    $split = explode('@',$service['User']['email']);
?>
```

The code above outputs an array with two elements inside it: one for `dipesh` and other for `some.com`. That is correct as expected.

Now I want a `MySQL` query that will perform `select query` to get record for `dipesh@.`

**Example**

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.email LIKE 'dipesh';
```

The code above returns all the records that contain `dipesh`, but I want only the ones that contain `dipesh@`.

Does `SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.email LIKE '%dipesh';` work?

If it does then what is the difference between the two?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your PHP code seems unrelated to your problem, but it sounds like you want `email = 'dipesh@'`, which matches `dipesh@` literally.  If you want `dipesh@` followed by anything, use `email LIKE 'dipesh@%'`.  The `%` is a wildcard meaning "match zero or more of any character."

Comment: Thanx for quick response and you got it right i want dipesh@...so appending % after queryString means just match dipesh@..?

Comment: `= 'dipesh@'` will only match exactly `"dipesh@"`.  `LIKE 'dipesh@%'` will match `"dipesh@"`, `"dipesh@some.com"`, and anything else with something after the `@` as long as it starts with `dipesh@`

Comment: Thanx for clarification you really are explosive dude...i thought i might use REGEX or other complex mysql clause but this seems very easy now...thanx a lot..1000000000000000000+ for u

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
   SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.email LIKE 'dipesh@';
```

and if you want to `dipesh@` followed by anything else

use this

```
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.email LIKE 'dipesh@%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to try this

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.email LIKE 'dipesh@%'";
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE 'dipesh@%';
```